# linq need to get count of columns that have values

Tags: linq

I have the following sample columns

```
ID  Comment    Analyzer  Incubator    Deanalyzer
--  -------    -------   ---------    ----------
23  Need Fast  5.6                    8.7
```

What I need is to show the results is the ID, Comments, then a count of 
how many columns had values. So in this case count would be 2 as only Analyzer and Deanalyzer have values. This is what I have so far:

```
    var result = from tb in db.Reports
    where tb.Id == 23
    select new { ID = tb.ID, 
                 Comments = tb.Comments,
                 Count = .. 

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clean but you could do:

```
var result = from tb in db.Reports
where tb.Id == 23
select new { ID = tb.ID, 
             Comments = tb.Comments,
             Count = (tb.Analyzer!= null ? 1 : 0) + (tb.Incubator != null ? 1 : 0) + (tb.Deanalyzer!= null ? 1 : 0)

            }
```

I wouldn't use this if you have lots of columns.

Comment: Thanks. How would you handle lots os columns as I have about 30 columns

Comment: 30 would be ok as long as you format the code so it is manageable and don't have hundreds of thousands of rows.